# Aframe performance and number of polygons

Tags: json, d3.js, aframe

I am seeing pretty poor performances on a page I am trying to build using A-Frame/D3.
I have 1300 polygons (800 boxes and 500 spheres) that compose a couple of barcharts and plot graphs to visualise data.
I can't load them in assets as their height, radius etc... depend on the data coming from JSON files (appended with D3).
I am experiencing 25fps when using WASD keys moving around and 10 fps when looking around with the mouse.
Is 1300 objects to render too much, or should i look somewhere else to figure out my performance issue?

thanks

Comment: Edit: I did not consider the merging option, since each bar and each sphere bears an interaction with the user through clicks and mouseenter/mouseleave (like popping up the underlying data as a text or changing the transparency of the clicked bar)

Comment: Perhaps try geometry instancing. Never used it, but it might help. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferGeometry